# SQL query based on time series data

Tags: sql, vertica

I have 2 tables like below:

```
create table parent_child
(
    parent_id int not null,
    child_id int not null
    
);

INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (117722, 273215);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (117722, 117936);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (117722, 117873);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (117722, 123305);

INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (104151, 240006);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (104151, 240005);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (104151, 239415);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (104151, 239414);

INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (5316, 118310);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (5316, 130627);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (5316, 298564);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (5316, 118311);
INSERT INTO parent_child (parent_id, child_id) VALUES (5316, 118312);
```

```
create table child
(
    child_id int not null,
    tstamp datetime not null,
    value float,
);

-- Parent 117722
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (273215, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  29);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (117936, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  52);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (117873, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  51);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (123305, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  31);

-- Parent 104151
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (240006, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  37);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (240005, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  88);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (239415, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  29);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (239414, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  19);

-- Parent 5316
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (118310, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  42);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (130627, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  11);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (298564, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  36);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (118311, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',  22);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (118312, '2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000',   9);

-- Parent 117722
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (273215, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  72);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (117936, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  99);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (117873, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  13);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (123305, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  24);

-- Parent 104151
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (240006, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  65);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (240005, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  63);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (239415, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  23);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (239414, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  15);

-- Parent 5316
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (118310, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  19);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (130627, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  22);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (298564, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  47);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (118311, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  54);
INSERT INTO child (child_id, tstamp, value) VALUES (118312, '2021-07-14 00:05:00.000000',  12);
```

The data in child table repeats every 5 minutes for each child. That is, for each child of a parent, there will be 288 data points. And this will further repeat for each day with a different (or same) value at a data point.

## Questions:

(1) Find out `parent_id`, `date_when_count_of_value_above_30_more_than_12_times_in_a_day`, `count_of_values_above_30_each_day` where value across all children of a parent exceeded 30 for more than 12 times a day and at least 3 days a week. The data points need not be consecutive. Put in other words, if the `MAX(value)` across all children of a parent at a data point (e.g. 2021-07-14 00:00:00.000000) is above 30, then that is counted as one occurance for that parent on that date.

(2) Find out `parent_id`, `latest_datetime_in_the_week`, `max_value_across_all_children_in_a_week` where the `value` across all children of a parent was maximum and the datetime when it was maximum. If more than one datetime has the same max value, then pick the latest datetime.

If these two queries can be combined in a single query, that is what I want. Otherwise, these can be 2 differet queries. If single query, then the output of question (2) will repeat for each row from question (1) and that is acceptable.

## Inputs:

A list of `parent_id`s for example, `WHERE parent_id IN (117722, 5316)`

## Sample output (if 2 queries are combined in one; column names can be anything, I am putting long names for brevity):

```
parent_id | date_when_count_of_value_above_30_more_than_12_times_in_a_day | count_of_values_above_30_each_day | max_value_across_all_children_in_a_week | latest_datetime_in_the_week
117722    | 2021-07-14                                                    | 13                                | 99                                      | 2021-07-09 16:15:00.000000
117722    | 2021-07-11                                                    | 28                                | 99                                      | 2021-07-09 16:15:00.000000
104151    | 2021-07-14                                                    | 19                                | 65                                      | 2021-07-11 18:30:00.000000
104151    | 2021-07-13                                                    | 27                                | 65                                      | 2021-07-11 18:30:00.000000
104151    | 2021-07-11                                                    | 36                                | 65                                      | 2021-07-11 18:30:00.000000
```

The above is just a sample output. Of course, a parent_id will not appear on the output if the number of occurances in a week is not more than 3.

Comment: Please tag your dbms with version.

Comment: Can you please explain figure of 288 data points?

Comment: oky.. Got it 24*12

Comment: 24 hrs = 1440 mins. So, if data appears in the tables every 5 minutes, then there are 288 entries per day per child

Comment: Can you share the possible variances of `value`? how quick does it change, how much does it change, are there "gentle curves" or peaks? I could use the Vertica `TIMESERIES` clause together with a `RANDOM()` or `RANDOMINT()` function to generate 288 evenly spaced child rows per day and child identifier with a few lines of code. Can I just use random numbers within a defined range for that?

Comment: @marcothesane The ```value```s are the metrics from the components of network devices. For example, a router is a network device and the components are CPU, memory,  buffer, etc. ```value``` holds the utilization of these components polled every 5 minutes (what is CPU utilization at 16:05, for example). Given this, there is no set pattern that these values will vary. A random number cannot be used in this case because there is not any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three selects, all depending on the parent id. And using Vertica's analytic limit clause: LIMIT 1 OVER()

```
WITH
w_p AS (
  SELECT
    parent_id
  , child.*
  FROM parent_child
  JOIN child USING(child_id)
)
,
o_30_count AS (
  SELECT
    parent_id
  , tstamp::DATE
  , SUM(CASE WHEN val > 30 THEN 1 END) AS over_30_count
  FROM w_p 
  GROUP BY 1,2 
  HAVING over_30_count > 12
)
,
max_per_week AS (
  SELECT
    parent_id
  , WEEK(tstamp)
  , MAX(val) AS max_per_week
  FROM w_p
  GROUP BY 1,2
  LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id ORDER BY max_per_week DESC)
)
,
last_max_per_week AS (
  SELECT
    parent_id
  , tstamp AS last_week_ts
  FROM w_p
  LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY parent_id,WEEK(tstamp) ORDER BY val DESC)
)
SELECT
  o_30_count.parent_id
, over_30_count
, max_per_week
, last_week_ts
FROM o_30_count 
JOIN max_per_week USING(parent_id)
JOIN last_max_per_week USING(parent_id);
```

Comment: thanks for your response. A couple of questions if you can help clarify wrt Vertica Analytic Database v9.1.1-5. (1) ```LIMIT 1 OVER()``` is not supported in this version. Is there a workaround? (2) The column alias ```over_30_count``` cannot be used in ```HAVING``` clause. So, I think I can use ```HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN val > 30 THEN 1 END)```. Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: The analytic limit clause `LIMIT (n) OVER(PARTITION BY (column_list) ORDER BY (column_list) )` has been around for years. Try again ...

Comment: I get this: AT, FOR, ISNULL, NOTNULL, OFFSET, TIME, WITH or '[' expected, got 'OVER'

Comment: This is not a typical Vertica error message. Vertica would say: `ERROR 4856:  Syntax error at or near "OVER" at character 176` . So it's an error message of a different SQL database.

Comment: You are right. I am running Vertica queries from IntelliJ IDEA and seems like there was a problem with the dialect selected. Everything is working as expected. Thanks for taking time out to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in Sybase. You can leverage the logic and convert Vertica specific. Also, For week I am taking year of week from timestamp. You can modify that as per your requirement. Like today -7 days or window based.

(1)

```
Select * from
(Select
p.parent_id                     as 'parent_id',
convert(varchar, c.tstamp, 101) as 'date_when_count_of_value_above_30_more_than_12_times_in_a_day',
count(*)                        as 'count_of_values_above_30_each_day '
from #parent_child p LEFT OUTER JOIN #child c
on p.child_id = c.child_id
where 
c.value > 30 and
p.parent_id in (5316, 117722, 104151)
group by 
convert(varchar, c.tstamp, 101), p.parent_id
having count(*) > 12) tb1
group by datepart(cwk, tb1.date_when_count_of_value_above_30_more_than_12_times_in_a_day), parent_id
having count(*) >=3
```

(2)

```
Select
parent_id      as 'parent_id',
MAX(tstamp)    as 'latest_datetime_in_the_week',
value          as 'max_value_across_all_children_in_a_week' 
from 
(Select
p.parent_id,c.tstamp,c.value from #parent_child p LEFT OUTER JOIN #child c
on p.child_id = c.child_id
JOIN 
(Select
MAX(c.value) as 'max_value'
from #parent_child p LEFT OUTER JOIN #child c
on p.child_id = c.child_id
where
datepart(cwk, tstamp) = 28
group by 
datepart(cwk, tstamp), p.parent_id) tbl1
ON c.value = tbl1.max_value) tbl2
group by parent_id, value
```

Answer (score 0):

For (1):

Note: *I moved parentId into the child table for readability*

```
WITH BYDAY AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as CountHiValsOnDay, parent_id, CAST(tstamp as date) as tsDate, DATEPART(week, CAST(tstamp as date)) as TheWeek, YEAR(CAST(tstamp as date)) as TheYear
    FROM child
    WHERE value > 30
    GROUP BY parent_id, CAST(tstamp as date)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 12
)
SELECT
    bd1.parent_id,
    bd1.tsDate,
    bd1.CountHiValsOnDay,
    bd2.CountThisWeek
FROM BYDAY bd1
    JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as CountThisWeek, jj.parent_id, jj.TheWeek, jj.TheYear
        FROM BYDAY jj
        GROUP BY jj.parent_id, jj.TheWeek, jj.TheYear
    ) bd2
      ON bd2.parent_id = bd1.parent_id AND
          bd2.TheWeek = bd1.TheWeek AND
          bd2.TheYear = bd1.TheYear
WHERE bd2.CountThisWeek >= 3
```

Comment: Thank you, Neal. I will try this once I am back. However, I was only focused on grouping by tstamp and that was giving me headache. What you have shown will work, I believe. You broke the tstamp, extracted date part and grouped on that. Thanks once again. I will feedback once I try this out.